# Create IronPython dictionary from JObject

Tags: c#, python, dictionary, json.net, ironpython

I am trying to set a variable for the script scope of `IronPython`. I want to use a `JObject` as a Python dictionary. This is what I tried.

```
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();

JObject childObject = new JObject();
childObject["child1"] = "test";
JObject dataObject = new JObject();
dataObject["key1"] = childObject;

scope.SetVariable("metaData", dataObject);
```

I can use the `metaData` variable, and also use the first key by calling `metaData["key1"]`. But when I'm trying to get to the next value by calling `metaData["key1"]["child1"]` I get the following error message: `Can not convert from System.String to System.Object.` How can I use my JSON Object as if it was a normal Python dictionary? The depth of my JSON Object will vary, so I need to be flexible with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me.

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
dynamic scope = engine.CreateScope();
scope.metaData = new JObject
{
    ["key1"] = new JObject
    {
        ["child1"] = "test",
    },
};
engine.Execute(@"
print metaData['key1']['child1']
foo = metaData['key1']
foo['bar'] = 'baz'
print metaData
", scope);
```

prints:

```
test
{ 
  "key1": { 
    "child1": "test", 
    "bar": "baz" 
  } 
}
```

It depends on what you're doing with the object within your script.

Just beware that behind the scenes, it is still a plain old json.net `JObject`, you cannot add any value to it.  You cannot add an IronPython `dict` for instance. It must be something that is or implicitly convertible to a `JToken`.